# $P(C\mid B)=P(C\mid\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(B\cap A_i))= \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(C\mid B\cap A_i) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

where $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing $ for $ i \ne j$
Is formula true?
P.S newbie in this area

Comment: You seem to have (mis) copied just a part of the intended question: The summation index should be $i$, not $n$. There must be an additional assumption about the $A_i$'s. Even then, unless $n=1$, it can happen that the right side of the proposed equation is $>1$, which would make the equation obviously false. I suggest you consider some small examples, say on probability spaces of two or three points.

Answer (score 0):

If $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ sum up to the entire sample space, yes, it is true. You can check [the law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Yeah, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ sum up to entire sample space, I have checked the link and i think that i now get it. Thank you.